# How to disable interaction between buttons of the same layout?

Tags: java, android

I have two sets of layouts, populated with buttons. Is there a way to disable any interaction between buttons of the same layout? I just need nothing to happen when I click one button and then the other from the same layout. I tagged each button with " and ", for buttons that belongs to upper and lower layouts. I have 5 of each kind.
I have some interaction beetwen buttons of oposite layouts and that's working fine (actually interaction works fine between any two given buttons and that's bad), but I don't want that interaction between buttons of the same layout.

Here's my game class, not all of it, just important parts. Also, I've removed code for rest of the buttons, only left for 4 buttons, 2 for each layout, to save some space here. I import some text from sqlite database, and randomly set it to my buttons.

```
final OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {

            private Button buttonClicked;

            public void onClick(View v) {


                Button button = (Button) v;
                button.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x003333));

                if (buttonClicked == null) {
                    // first button is clicked
                    buttonClicked = button;
                } else {
                    // second button is clicked
                    if (buttonClicked.getTag().equals(button.getTag())) {
                        button.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x66FF33));
                        buttonClicked.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x66FF33));
                      buttonClicked.setEnabled(false);
                        button.setEnabled(false);
                    } else {
                        buttonClicked.setEnabled(false);
                        buttonClicked.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                        buttonClicked.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFCC99));
                        button.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                    }
                    buttonClicked = null;

            }
     };




    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.game);

        a1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA1);
        a2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA2);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB2);

        nextQuestion();
        }

        public void nextQuestion() {


        TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();

        try{ 

            mDbHelper.open();

            Cursor c = mDbHelper.getTestData(generateWhereClause());

            mAnsweredQuestions.add(c.getLong(0));

            ArrayList<MyStruct> labelsA = new ArrayList<MyStruct>();
            ArrayList<MyStruct> labelsB = new ArrayList<MyStruct>();

            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(2), "1")); // this tag should be the same to button that matches
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(3), "1"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(4), "2"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(5), "2"));


            Collections.shuffle(labelsA);
            Collections.shuffle(labelsB);


            pitanje.setText(c.getString(1));

            a1.setText(labelsA.get(0).label);
            a1.setTag(labelsA.get(0).tag);
            a1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a1.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            a1.setEnabled(true);
            b1.setText(labelsB.get(0).label);
            b1.setTag(labelsB.get(0).tag);
            b1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b1.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            b1.setEnabled(true);
            a2.setText(labelsA.get(1).label);
            a2.setTag(labelsA.get(1).tag);
            a2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a2.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            a2.setEnabled(true);
            b2.setText(labelsB.get(1).label);
            b2.setTag(labelsB.get(1).tag);
            b2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b2.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            b2.setEnabled(true);


        }


        finally{ 
            mDbHelper.close();
        }
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:gravity="top|center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPitanje"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ovde ce biti postavljeno pitanje"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="360dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/kolona1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bA1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="41dp"
                android:layout_gravity="clip_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1.5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:tag="l"
                android:text="A1"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bA2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="41dp"
                android:text="A2"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1.5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1.5dp"
                android:tag="l"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bA3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="41dp"
                android:text="A3"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1.5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1.5dp"
                android:tag="l"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bA4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="41dp"
                android:text="A4"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1.5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1.5dp"
                android:tag="l"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bA5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="41dp"
                android:text="A5"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1.5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1.5dp"
                android:tag="l"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bA6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="41dp"
                android:text="A6"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1.5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1.5dp"
                android:tag="l"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bA7"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="41dp"
                android:text="A7"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1.5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1.5dp"
                android:tag="l"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bA8"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="41dp"
                android:text="A8"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginTop="1.5dp"
                android:tag="l"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/kolona2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="3dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bB1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="41dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top|fill_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1.5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                android:tag="r"
                android:text="B1"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bB2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="41dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1.5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1.5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                android:tag="r"
                android:text="B2"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bB3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="41dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1.5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1.5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                android:tag="r"
                android:text="B3"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bB4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="41dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1.5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1.5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                android:tag="r"
                android:text="B4"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bB5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="41dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1.5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1.5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                android:tag="r"
                android:text="B5"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bB6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="41dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1.5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1.5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                android:tag="r"
                android:text="B6"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bB7"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="41dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1.5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1.5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                android:tag="r"
                android:text="B7"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bB8"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="41dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1.5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                android:tag="r"
                android:text="B8"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bIzlaz"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="42dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Izlaz!"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPoeni"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tvScore"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="21sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvVreme"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="30"
                android:textColor="#ff0000"
                android:textSize="21sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I took a look at it, but I'm confused by your explanation. Could you post the XML for this and explain what you want to achieve exactly (what is the purpose of this)?

Comment: You can now see XML above. I have this game that compares terms, like actors for example. I place first names in left column and surnames in right column. I have 8 buttons in each column. Now when a user press a button on left side (for example name Adam), he will now press the button on the right column with setText name Sandler. For Adam Sandler. :)) And that's OK, it works fine.

Comment: But I have a problem, if a user press Adam on the left, and then he does not his surname and change his mind and want to select another first name on the left side to try another actor, lets say Rober De Niro, my code will now compare Adam and his second press Robert, and that's not good. I need in that case nothing to happen, so user can roam freely on one side without any consequences.

Comment: And [here](https://github.com/Nabukodonosor/spojnice/blob/master/spojnice.java) you can see my whole Spojnice.java class, maybe it can help too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `getParent` method and compare the parents of both views. If the parent is the same, then the buttons are in the same layout and nothing should happen.

Change your else:

```
} else {
    // second button is clicked
```

... to an else if:

```
// only do stuff if buttons are in different layouts
} else if (button.getParent () != buttonClicked.getParent()) {
     // second button is clicked
```

Comment: OK, let me try this, and I'll let you now.

Comment: I think you should just use `==` comparison for parents instead of `.equals` as you need them to be the same object and not just equal objects.

Comment: Well I THINK it's working, but can't really tell until I solve another problem. When I press a button I set green color to it, and when I press another in the same column it also get green, but the previous one stays green. Is there a way to loose that green color on previusly clicked button?

Comment: @AleksG hmm, I guess you're right. I'll change it above. Thanks!

Comment: Can you try and compile on your computer and see waht's working and what's not? I think it's faster that way.

Comment: No, man, sorry. Don't have the time for that. Logic tells me that it should work. You could have other problems in the code, or something that I haven't noticed. Good luck and post an answer if you resolve it :)

Comment: No problem mate. Well, I inserted Toast for correct and incorrect answers, just to follow, what's happening, and I guess you did your part, nothing happens when I click inbetween left side buttons, that's ok, but, when I click the right side button, after the last one clicked on the left side, I get "Incorrect" toast even dow I know it's correct pair. Can you tell from my code why's that happening?

Comment: I guess it keeps counting number of clicks. So if click once on the left side that's first click, and if click once more on the left side that's second click.