# Two onClickListeners and interaction between them

Tags: java, android

Lets say I have two onClickListeners, A and B, and some buttons asigned to them. Is there a way for each clicked button that "belongs" to onClickListener A to listen, wait or whatever until next button is clicked and if it's from onClickedListener B to do some code after that, it's not important what, and if it's from onClickListener A to stay put and do nothing but wait next click and also wait like the previous button and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I edited my answer to kind of do what the other question asked. Let me know if it makes sense. I won't do the work for you, so this is a simple example that kind of shows you what the logic is.

```
//This is how you set the TAG so you have it. But I know you use getTag, so I am not sure     
//what you are using it for.
a1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA1);
a2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA2);
b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB1);
b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB2);
a1.setTag("A");
a2.setTag("A");
b1.setTag("B");
b2.setTag("B");


View.OnClickListener listener = new View.onClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String tag = (String)view.getTag();
        if(tag.equals("A")
            //example on one B button with assumed TAG of "B"
            someButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
            //deregister all your A Views, but again, I'll do one as an example
            //in this case I'll quickly just deregister the A button or view just clicked
            view.setOnClickListener(null);
        else
            if(tag.equals("B")) {
                /*I guess do your thing here but deregister all the B views again
                and register all the A views again*/
                someButton.setOnClickListener(null);
                otherAButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
            }
    }
});
```

So I make some assumptions to shorten the code up. For example. Set all your A `View`s with the `"A"` tag using the `setTag` method, vice versa with the B `View`s. Also I assume you want the A views to start off listening to clicks, so when the Activity or Fragment is first launched, thats where you set `listener` to the A views via `setOnClickListener`.

Comment: [Check out this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754577/how-to-disable-interaction-between-buttons-of-the-same-layout), maybe you'll get idea why I asked this. On the link I gave you, I tried to find solution for my problem, but I didn't so I'm trying to do this like I asked here.

Comment: Ohhh, in that case you can set the listener values in the A views as null to deregister them. So when you click on an A value, register the B views and deregister the A views. I'll do a quick example with the above.

Comment: OK, let me know when you finish. Thanks a lot. I'm trying to finish this for the last month and no luck.

Comment: I finished a quick example. Keep in mind it was quick and I did not test the code. It is also an example so I recommend testing it with a single A `View` and a single B `View` to understand how it works. But it should give you the behavior you seek.

Comment: The problem is, when you said to setTags, I already have some tags attached to my buttons (for example A1 and B1 have tag "1", so I can compare and pair them), so I don't know how to set tags you mentioned. [here](https://github.com/Nabukodonosor/spojnice/blob/master/spojnice.java) you can see my whole game class, mayble you'll have some idea how to wrap this up.

Comment: It doesn't have to be the Tag. It can be the views `android:id`. IN your case I do notice you use `getTag`. But I have no idea what `MyStruct` is or what you do when you create one. Not enough context. My suggestion is to make the example separately so you understand what exactly is happening. Then once you understand try to make it fit into your current code. You can alternatively make a method that just go through all the B views and just run deregister them, and register them that way. There are several ways you can go about this.

Comment: I added how to set the TAG above. If you are using the TAG for other reasons you can append them together and splitting them using whatever delimiter you'd like. Or you can use the substring of the TAG if all your tags start with like `a` or `b`. Again,  I don't have the context to tailor it for you, neither would I do so as its your code :P

Comment: Did you see [this](https://github.com/Nabukodonosor/spojnice/blob/master/spojnice.java)?