# How to tell my code which tags to check in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have this code to set some tags, I'm setting two tags, after adding this lines to strings.xml:

```
<item type="id" name="KOLONA1"/>
<item type="id" name="KOLONA2"/>

a1.setTag(R.id.KOLONA1, labelsA.get(0).tag);
```

and in my onClickListener I have some code which checks tags:

```
if (buttonClicked.getTag().equals(button.getTag())) {

//some code
}
```

In this specific check, my code should check second, labelsA.get(0).tag tag, but it does not, it check the first one, R.id.KOLONA. How to tell my code which tags to check?

[image: Example buttons]

Comment: how about a switch with the id's as cases

Comment: Not a bad idea. But how would you implement that in my case?

Comment: Actually I wouldn't know how to implement switch statement here, cause I need to compare two clicked buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a specific tag by id by using `View.getTag(int tag)`.  I think what you are looking for is `button.getTag(R.id.KOLONA1)`.  The documentation can be found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag(int)

Comment: This isn't an answer, it should be a comment.

Comment: Changed to the form of a statement.

Comment: Yes but this is only for one tag, I need two tags for each button. Also I wont know what tag is it so I can place R.id.KOLONA1, I just need to check if they are equal or not.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I think you should review your original post and make it more clear with what exactly you are trying to accomplish as I'm a little confused.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754577/how-to-disable-interaction-between-buttons-of-the-same-layout). One of my countless tries to solve that. And I'm still struggling.

Answer (score 0):

Something simple like this could be what you are looking for:

```
if (buttonClicked.getId() == button.getId()
     && buttonClicked.getTag().equals(button.getTag())) {

    //some code
}
```

Or if you are feeling really paranoid:

```
if (buttonClicked.getId() == button.getId()
     && buttonClicked.getParent() == button.getParent()
     && buttonClicked.getTag().equals(button.getTag())) {

    //some code
}
```

**UPDATE**: I just realised that the `getTag()` is redundant since if they have the same ID and the same parent they must be the same, so:

```
if (buttonClicked.getId() == button.getId()
     && buttonClicked.getParent() == button.getParent()) {

    //some code
}
```

Comment: OK, I will try. This is my desperate try to solve [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754577/how-to-disable-interaction-between-buttons-of-the-same-layout). :((

Comment: I need them, if they are from same parent (or have the same ID, which is the same), to do absolutely nothing. Only if they are not from the same parent to act.

Comment: @marjanbaz In that case, use `buttonClicked.getId() == button.getId() && buttonClicked.getParent() != button.getParent()`.

Comment: Are you sure that they should have the same id? Isn't the id in this case KOLONA1 and KOLONA2? I placed that tag for all buttons in left and right column, so KOLONA1 is for all left buttons and KOLONA2 is for all right side buttons. And I need them to act only if it's interaction between columns.

Comment: I placed screenshot in my original post, just for you to see what i'm talking about.

Comment: AM I right in saying that the first column of buttons have IDs KOLONA1 to KOLONA8 and the second KOLONB1 to KOLONB8, but KOLONAn and KOLONBn have identical tags? Furthermore, both sets of buttons are within separate vertical LinearLayouts? Posting your XML file would help here, but if my assumption is correct, then 'buttonClicked.getTag().equals(button.getTag()) && buttonClicked.getParent() != button.getParent() && buttonClicked.getParent().getParent() == button.getParent().getParent()` would work. (It might also be better to put each pair in a horizonal LinearLayout instead)

Comment: @marjanbaz I see from [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754577/how-to-disable-interaction-between-buttons-of-the-same-layout) that my assumption above looks correct. But, you have the tags hard-coded as 'l' and 'r' for the two columns, so there is no easy way to relate the left and right columns. I think this would be solved much easier if you used the same IDs for the corresponding buttons in the two columns.

Comment: You mean same id's in xml layout file? But how to findViewById in my java class then?

Comment: And from previous question...No, those two ID's KOLONA1 and KOLONA2 are set in strings.xml. Check out beginning of my original post for that. Both sets of buttons are in two separate vertical lineral layouts. [Here's the link](https://github.com/Nabukodonosor/spojnice/blob/master/spojnice.xml) for my XML layout.

Comment: [And here the link](https://github.com/Nabukodonosor/spojnice/blob/master/Spojnice2.java) for my game class.