# How to make only last two clicks active?

Tags: java, android

I need another aproach to my problem. So, whenever I click a button (I have 16 of them) it stays "active" and wait until buttonClicked.getTag().equals(button.getTag())) if statement is true. This is so bad for me. So, I click first button, and then 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th and let's say 5th button has the same tag as my 1st clicked button, and now 1st and 5th button gets paired and disabled. How to make only last two clicked buttons count? So, in my example I need 5th clicked button to compare with 4th, not with the 1st one. But the 1st one stays active all the way.

```
final OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {

            private Button buttonClicked;

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Button button = (Button) v;
                button.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x003333));

                if (buttonClicked == null) {
                    // first button is clicked
                    buttonClicked = button;
             } else if (buttonClicked.getParent() != button.getParent()) {
                    // second button is clicked
                    if (buttonClicked.getTag().equals(button.getTag())) {
                        Toast.makeText(Spojnice.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        button.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x66FF33));
                        buttonClicked.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x66FF33));
                        buttonClicked.setEnabled(false);
                        button.setEnabled(false);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Spojnice.this, "Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                 buttonClicked = null;
                }       
            }

     };
```

So, on the screenshow below I first pressed Aquarius then Pisces then Crux then Aquila and in the end Vodolija. So it remembered all the way my first click and then once it met condition that they are not from the same parent(not in the same linear layout) it compared them. And this is my problem. I need to compare only last two clicked, in this case Aquila and Vodolija. That will result as the wrong answer, cause they are not the pair, but that's irelevant now. So, when I click on the first button in the right layout (Vodlija in this case) I need to compare it with the last one clicked in the left layout, not the first one, and that Aquila in this case. How to do that?

[image]

Comment: Can you simplify the question. Exactly what are you trying to do?

Comment: [Here you ca see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754577/how-to-disable-interaction-between-buttons-of-the-same-layout) what I'm trying to acomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with formatting

```
package rs.androidaplikacije.toplo_hladno;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.LightingColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Spojnice extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

       Button previousButton = null;
       //private Button buttonClicked;

        //private static final Integer[] idArrayA = {R.id.bA1, R.id.bA2, R.id.bA3, R.id.bA4, R.id.bA5, R.id.bA6, R.id.bA7, R.id.bA8};
        //private static final Integer[] idArrayB = {R.id.bB1, R.id.bB2, R.id.bB3, R.id.bB4, R.id.bB5, R.id.bB6, R.id.bB7, R.id.bB8};

        private int brojacIgara = 0;
        private int counter = 0;

        MyCount brojacVremena = new MyCount(450000, 1000);

        // labelForButton and tagForButton
           class MyStruct {
           public MyStruct (String lab, String t){
            label = lab;
            tag = t;
        }
           private String label;
           private String tag;
           }

           final OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {

                private Button buttonClicked;

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Button button = (Button) v;
                    button.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x003333));

                    if (buttonClicked == null) {
                        // first button is clicked
                        debug.setText("\n tag " + button.getTag() + " " + button.getParent());
                        buttonClicked = button;
                        // only do stuff if buttons are in different layouts
                    } else{
                            debug.setText("\n tag " + button.getTag() + " " + button.getParent());
                if (!button.getParent ().equals(buttonClicked.getParent())) {
                     // second button is clicked
                 if(buttonClicked.getTag().equals(button.getTag()) ){

                    // second button is clicked and same tag but different button

                    Toast.makeText(Spojnice.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    button.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x66FF33));
                    buttonClicked.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x66FF33));
                    buttonClicked.setEnabled(false);
                    button.setEnabled(false);
                    buttonClicked = null;
                    } else {
                    //reset LightingColorFilter first
                    Toast.makeText(Spojnice.this, "Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    buttonClicked = null;//i guess you want to make it back to initial state so null and current button

                    }
                   }else{
                       //same button clicked show message or un toggle?
                       buttonClicked = button;
                   }
                }
                    }       
                };

    /*final OnClickListener clickListener2 = new OnClickListener() {
        Button a = null;
        public void onClick(View v) {

            onButtonClicked(Button b) {
                if (a != null && a.getTag().equals(b.getTag()) {
                    System.out.println("Hurray, a match");
                } else {
                    a = b;
                }
            }

        }

    };*/


    LinkedList<Long> mAnsweredQuestions = new LinkedList<Long>();

    private String generateWhereClause(){
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (Long l : mAnsweredQuestions){
            result.append(" AND _ID <> " + l);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
    private TextView pitanje, score, vreme, debug, debug2;

    Button a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,izlaz;
    MediaPlayer buttonBack;
    public boolean music;

    Runnable mLaunchTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            nextQuestion();
            brojacVremena.start();
        }
     };
    Runnable mLaunchTaskFinish = new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            finish();
         }
      };
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);   //full screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.spojnice);

        Typeface pitanjeType = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "myriad.ttf");
        Typeface dugmad = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Bebas.ttf");
        Typeface AB = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "ARIALN.TTF");
        buttonBack = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button31);
        a1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSpojniceA1);
        a2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSpojniceA2);
        a3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSpojniceA3);
        a4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSpojniceA4);
        a5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSpojniceA5);
        a6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSpojniceA6);
        a7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSpojniceA7);
        a8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSpojniceA8);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSpojniceB1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSpojniceB2);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSpojniceB3);
        b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSpojniceB4);
        b5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSpojniceB5);
        b6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSpojniceB6);
        b7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSpojniceB7);
        b8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSpojniceB8);
        //izlaz = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bIzlazSpojnice);
        //izlaz.setTypeface(dugmad);
        //score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPoeniSpojnice);
        //score.setTypeface(dugmad);
        //vreme = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvVremeSpojnice);
        //vreme.setTypeface(dugmad);
        pitanje = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPitanjeSpojnice);
        pitanje.setTypeface(pitanjeType);
        b1.setTypeface(AB);
        b2.setTypeface(AB);
        b3.setTypeface(AB);
        b4.setTypeface(AB);
        b5.setTypeface(AB);
        b6.setTypeface(AB);
        b7.setTypeface(AB);
        b8.setTypeface(AB);
        a1.setTypeface(AB);
        a2.setTypeface(AB);
        a3.setTypeface(AB);
        a4.setTypeface(AB);
        a5.setTypeface(AB);
        a6.setTypeface(AB);
        a7.setTypeface(AB);
        a8.setTypeface(AB);
        debug = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDebug);
        debug2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDebug2);


        SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        music = getPrefs.getBoolean("checkbox", true);

        nextQuestion();
        brojacVremena.start();  //startuje brojac vremena

        }

        public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {

            public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
                super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTask,500);

            }

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                //vreme.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

            }

        }

    public void nextQuestion() {

        brojacIgara = brojacIgara + 1;


        TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);
        DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

        if(!myDbHelper.checkDataBase()){
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();
        }

        try{    //Pokusava da otvori db

            mDbHelper.open();  //baza otvorena

            Cursor c = mDbHelper.getSpojnice(generateWhereClause());

            mAnsweredQuestions.add(c.getLong(0));

            ArrayList<MyStruct> labelsA = new ArrayList<MyStruct>();
            ArrayList<MyStruct> labelsB = new ArrayList<MyStruct>();

            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(2), "1")); // this tag should be the same to button that matches
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(3), "1"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(4), "2"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(5), "2"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(6), "3"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(7), "3"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(8), "4"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(9), "4"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(10), "5"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(11), "5"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(12), "6"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(13), "6"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(14), "7"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(15), "7"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(16), "8"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(17), "8"));

            Collections.shuffle(labelsA);
            Collections.shuffle(labelsB);

            if (brojacIgara < 4){

            pitanje.setText(c.getString(1));

            a1.setText(labelsA.get(0).label);
            a1.setTag(labelsA.get(0).tag);
            a1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a1.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            a1.setEnabled(true);
            b1.setText(labelsB.get(0).label);
            b1.setTag(labelsB.get(0).tag);
            b1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b1.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            b1.setEnabled(true);
            a2.setText(labelsA.get(1).label);
            a2.setTag(labelsA.get(1).tag);
            a2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a2.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            a2.setEnabled(true);
            b2.setText(labelsB.get(1).label);
            b2.setTag(labelsB.get(1).tag);
            b2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b2.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            b2.setEnabled(true);
            a3.setText(labelsA.get(2).label);
            a3.setTag(labelsA.get(2).tag);
            a3.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a3.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            a3.setEnabled(true);
            b3.setText(labelsB.get(2).label);
            b3.setTag(labelsB.get(2).tag);
            b3.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b3.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            b3.setEnabled(true);
            a4.setText(labelsA.get(3).label);
            a4.setTag(labelsA.get(3).tag);
            a4.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a4.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            a4.setEnabled(true);
            b4.setText(labelsB.get(3).label);
            b4.setTag(labelsB.get(3).tag);
            b4.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b4.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            b4.setEnabled(true);
            a5.setText(labelsA.get(4).label);
            a5.setTag(labelsA.get(4).tag);
            a5.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a5.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            a5.setEnabled(true);
            b5.setText(labelsB.get(4).label);
            b5.setTag(labelsB.get(4).tag);
            b5.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b5.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            b5.setEnabled(true);
            a6.setText(labelsA.get(5).label);
            a6.setTag(labelsA.get(5).tag);
            a6.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a6.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            a6.setEnabled(true);
            b6.setText(labelsB.get(5).label);
            b6.setTag(labelsB.get(5).tag);
            b6.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b6.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            b6.setEnabled(true);
            a7.setText(labelsA.get(6).label);
            a7.setTag(labelsA.get(6).tag);
            a7.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a7.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            a7.setEnabled(true);
            b7.setText(labelsB.get(6).label);
            b7.setTag(labelsB.get(6).tag);
            b7.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b7.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            b7.setEnabled(true);
            a8.setText(labelsA.get(7).label);
            a8.setTag(labelsA.get(7).tag);
            a8.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a8.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            a8.setEnabled(true);
            b8.setText(labelsB.get(7).label);
            b8.setTag(labelsB.get(7).tag);
            b8.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b8.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
            b8.setEnabled(true);
            }else{
                brojacVremena.cancel();

                mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTaskFinish,4000);
                //SwarmLeaderboard.submitScore(7427, counter);
            }

        }


        finally{    // kada zavrsi sa koriscenjem baze podataka, zatvara db
            mDbHelper.close();
        }
        /*izlaz.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(music == true){
                    buttonBack.start();
                        }
                finish();   
            }
        });*/
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {


    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        brojacVremena.cancel();
    }

}
**strong text**
```

Comment: "are these toggle buttons?" No, buttons you see on image. [Here's my whole](https://github.com/Nabukodonosor/spojnice/blob/master/spojnice.java) game class, to paint a better picture.

Comment: "I assume you want to compare the previous two buttons clicked?".....I need to compare last two clicked. so 1st and 2nd, then 2nd and 3rd, 3rd and 4th and so on. My code now does not do this now.

Comment: "This seems buggy too. why will the parents be different? If its the same panel/ container ?".....well they are not the same. You can see 2 layouts on the image, left and right, in each 8 buttons. I only need to compare buttons between different layouts. [Here you can see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754577/how-to-disable-interaction-between-buttons-of-the-same-layout) what is my problem actually.

Comment: well even so my code might work if you can give it a try as the buttons wont be equal but tags will be. Or you can use the parent part. but basically checking if same button not clicked again

Comment: This code of your is not good. Now it compares buttons from the same layout also, and that's not good for me.

Comment: check now, made it parent.

Comment: but maybe you should have a different approach. more data driven. Add the buttons to an array list. on click see which button clicked by searching list. Compare indexes so you know exactly which button was clicked ...

Comment: are you sure for one parent only 1 tag is there per button?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27983/discussion-between-tgkprog-and-marjanbaz)

Comment: Mate, your last try worked! I'm 99% positive! Thanks a lot. I will know for sure once I finish some other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to remember one button previously clicked.
Now, if another button is clicked, compare it's tag's value to the tag value of the previous button. If they are the same -- bingo.
If not, set the previous button to the curren button and continue.

In pseudo java code:

```
Button a = null;

onButtonClicked(Button b) {
    if (a != null && a.getTag().equals(b.getTag()) {
        System.out.println("Hurray, a match");
    } else {
        a = b;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried to make something from your idea but it did not work. Can you use my code above, and implement your idea? I just don't have any more ideas how to wrap this thing up.